# Ask to user the Path to export File on C# Console

Tags: c#, file, replace

I am new at programming and I'm trying to add into a string variable the path to create a txt File. However I'm not getting it right if can it be done using Replace or Concat. I have never used that on C#. Here´s what I´ve done so far:

```
string path = @"###";
do
{
    Console.Write("Insert the path in oder to export data: ");
    string temp = Console.ReadLine();
} 
while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path));

path = path.Replace("###", "temp");
```

Comment: You need to provide a better problem statement and desired functionality.  What do you want this to do?  What have you found to be the issue when you debug?  Remember _to debug_

Comment: It's really not clear what you are doing there. Do you want a loop that continues to ask input until the user enters a path? Why are you declaring temp and not assigning the result of `ReadLine` to path directly ? Why are you initializing path to "###" ?

Comment: The reason I initialized path to @"###" was in order to replace from the input from the user. So I could add the path the variable, however the replace does not seem to work using the temp variable to it.

Comment: But why do you need to replace in the first place? You could just store the input in path directly?

Comment: also, `temp` is declared in the `do` loop block, so it's local to that block, and will be out of scope outside of that block

Answer (score 3):

The following line

```
path = path.Replace("###", "temp");
```

replaces the part `###` in the path with the literal string `temp`.

At the end of the operation, *contents* of your `path` variable will be "temp".

You don't really need to do a `Replace` at all. Instead,

```
string path = string.Empty;
do
{
    Console.Write("Insert the path in oder to export data: ");
    path = Console.ReadLine();
} 
while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path));
```

will assign the user entered path into your `path` variable.

Comment: Will it add @ to the variable in order to export data to Txt? Or it has to come from the user?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: @Ricardo your IDE lets you make adjustments, test and debug.  You should _use it_.  You can see for yourself [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zRsL56) that any normal path inputs typed in work as expected.  The `@` character in a string assigment just means its a verbatim string literal, its only useful when the string is typed _in code_ so that no escaping happens